# VB.NET - Adding columns to DataGridView's in a list

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a program where i let the user dynamically add DataGridViews to the interface, those are also added to a list for easy management. All of the DataGridViews have their own datasources. I am using a Databinding source to get different DataGridViewTextBoxColumns to add.

The problem is the following:
When the user adds the first table the following code runs:

```
dataGridList(dataGridList.Count -1).Clear()
dataGridList(dataGridList.Count -1).Add(NameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn)
```

No problem there and the right data is displayed, but when the user adds the second table i get an exception thrown:

> "Provided column already belongs to the datagrid view"

I think this is strange since i access different DataGridView's right?

The point of all of this is to be able to view different columns in all the DataGridViews depending on the users choices.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How are you determining what NameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn is?  What I mean is how is your list of textBoxColumns you mentioned created?

It seems likely that you actually need to create a New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn to add with the appropriate properties set.

You can add a column in code something like this:

```
        Dim col As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        col.DataPropertyName = "PropertyName"
        col.HeaderText = "SomeText"
        col.Name = "colWhateverName"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(col)
```

Be sure to set the appropriate property name etc.  You can copy it from the existing column too...

```
col.DataPropertyName = NameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName
```

For example.

Comment: Im probably lost...
The DataBindingSource i created in the designer has the datasource "WeightData", a class where i download all the information for each row from an SQL LINQ quiery. The WeightData class contains a number of propertys ans the different columns like "NameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn" are the same as those propertys.. The datasources for the different DataGridView's is a list of "WeightData"...
 I might be totaly lost??.

Comment: I am actually talking about the columns not the content for them.  Instead of adding one that you created from the designer you need to create a new instance of a column for the gridView. with the appropriate properties.  The designer creates 1 instance of a column if it gets added more than one time its trying to add the same one. Eidted above.

Answer (score 0):

Like above you need a new instance for each grid view and assign the columns to the new gridview which you could do on postback.

Comment: The DataGridView is a Windows Forms control, so this isn't an ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did. I choose the column via my DB search or table, then mesh both into one DGV.  Like this. I just played with it and it works now to properly align the rows. This is a little off topic as it's DB, but Im guessing similar methods would simplify adding data from other sources.

```
tempAdt = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT firstName FROM Employees",connector)
tableCommand = New OleDbCommandBuilder(tempAdt)

tableAdaptor = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM userTable", connector)
tableCommand = New OleDbCommandBuilder(tableAdaptor)

Dim startTable2 As New DataTable

tempAdt.Fill(startTable2)
tableAdaptor.Fill(startTable2)
```

Mainly I used two different adapters, and it will list them side by side in DGV